# Inverse of complex (NxN) matrix in delphi

Tags: delphi, matrix-inverse

In general, I want to compute the inverse of a complex square (NxN) matrix.

F.ex I have a 5x5 matrix :

```
Ybus = [ 
   6.2500 -18.6950i, -5.0000 +15.0000i, -1.2500 + 3.7500i,   0,                 0 ; 
  -5.0000 +15.0000i, 10.8333 -32.4150i, -1.6667 + 5.0000i,  -1.6667 + 5.0000i, -2.5000 + 7.5000i; 
  -1.2500 + 3.7500i, -1.6667 + 5.0000i, 12.9167 -38.6950i, -10.0000 +30.0000i, 0; 
   0,                -1.6667 + 5.0000i, -10.0000+30.0000i,  12.9167 -38.6950i, -1.2500 + 3.7500i; 
   0,                -2.5000 + 7.5000i, 0,                  -1.2500 + 3.7500i,  3.7500 -11.2100i;
]
```

How can I calculate the inverse (Zbus = inverse (Ybus)) of this matrix using Delphi?

Comment: What is the relation to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33464202/inverse-matrix-code-for-delphi ? Copyright violation?

Comment: You probably don't want to form the inverse. Usually that's inefficient.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I read that post and thought it was an interesting question. It was not possible to answer that question because its on hold. There was a link to ask a "new" question, which I did. I hope its useful for Azfar Muhammed II. Im new here, so please let me know if it should be done differently.

Comment: @ChristianHolmJørgensen It's perfectly fine to do what you did. The reservation that I have is that Azfar doesn't know enough about linear algebra to really know what question to ask. This sort of subject doesn't lend itself to black box solutions.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes I agree about performance perspective. But I think also it must be put in context of absolute time to compute the inverse on the used system. I updated the answer below with some profiling. Im on a fast PC, so if one is not, further optimization considerations might be needed.

Comment: In terms of performance, it's much more efficient to operate directly on complex valued matrices. It doesn't matter how fast your computer is, the algo will be faster with complex valued matrices than with the tricks that you use. Those tricks are quite useful for exploration. I've used similar methods in the past when scoping out work. But for real world work, you usually need to work directly with complex scalars. But again, that's not my main point. My main point is that Azfar is likely mistaken in the belief that forming the inverse matrix is the way to solve the problem.

Comment: It's not clear to me what trouble you're having with the task that would prompt you to post this question. [The Wikipedia article on matrix inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix) shows several ways. It seems like it would just be a matter of selecting a method and writing the code.

Comment: @Rob It's hard to do this well, the code is tricky to write correctly, and which method to use depends very much on the properties of the matrix. Furthermore, it is very commonly the case that inverting is a bad idea in terms of performance and stability. Typically it is best on both scores to decompose and back substitute. Christian per se has no problems and is posting on behalf of another user who has problems expressing what his task really is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There exists a [Matrix libray for Delphi](http://www.shokhirev.com/nikolai/programs/tools/PasMatLib/download.html) written by Mr. Nikolai Shokhirev (GNU2 Licensed).
It is not a complete library, but a good starting point.
Among others it is ***only*** capable of computing the inverse of a real valued Matrix.
But there is a way to compute the inverse of a complex matrix using real valued matrices:

According to [this Matlab ressource](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/49373-complex-matrix-inversion-by-real-matrix-inversion), a given complex square matrix M = A + i*B, its inverse is also a complex square matrix Z = X + i*Y, where A, B and X, Y are all real matrices. It is found that 
           M^-1 = Z or 
(A + i*B)^-1 = (A + B*A^-1*B)^-1 - i*(B + A*B^-1*A)^-1 
Provided that those matrices involved inversion must be nonsingular.

The following code finds the inverse of the complex Ybus matrix using the matrix library and the Matlab reference, and can also be used in a general to find the inverse of complex NxN matrix:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, DateUtils,

  // from matrix library
  // http://www.shokhirev.com/nikolai/programs/tools/PasMatLib/download.html
  uDynObjAlg,
  uDynArrays,
  uMatTypes;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

// extra matrix utils:
function CMat2Str(AMatrix: ICArr2D): String;
var
  row : Integer;
  col : Integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  for row := 1 to AMatrix.Dim1 do
  begin
    for col := 1 to AMatrix.Dim2 do
    begin
       Result := Result + CmplxToStr0(AMatrix[row, col], 10, 3) + ' ';
    end;
    Result := Result +#13#10;
  end;
  Result := Result;
end;

function Mat2Str(AMatrix: IFArr2D): String;
var
  row : Integer;
  col : Integer;
  s : string;
begin
  Result := '';
  for row := 1 to AMatrix.Dim1 do
  begin
    for col := 1 to AMatrix.Dim2 do
    begin
       Str(AMatrix[row, col]:10:3,s);
       Result := Result + s + ' ';
    end;
    Result := Result + ';'+#13#10;
  end;
end;

function MtAddMt(const M1: IFArr2D; const M2: IFArr2D): IFArr2D;
var
  row: TInt;
  col : TInt;
  t: IFArr2D;
begin
  if (M1.Lo1<>M2.Lo1) or ( M1.Hi1<>M1.Hi1) or (M1.Lo2<>M2.Lo2) or ( M1.Hi2<>M1.Hi2) then
    Raise ERangeError.Create(RS_LimMismatch);
  t := TFArr2D.Create(M1,true);
  for row := t.Lo1 to t.Hi1 do
    for col := t.Lo2 to t.Hi2 do
      t[row,col] := t[row,col] + M2[row, col];
  result := t;
end;


procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
const
  cInversionCount = 1000;

var
  YBus : ICArr2D;
  ZBus : ICArr2D;

  YBusRe: IFArr2D;
  YBusIm: IFArr2D;
  YBusReInv : IFArr2D;
  YBusImInv : IFArr2D;

  row, col : Integer;

  ZBusRe : IFArr2D;
  ZBusIm : IFArr2D;

  timeStart: TDateTime;
  timeStop : TDateTime;

  n : Integer;

begin
  YBus := TCArr2D.Create(1,5, 1,5);

  // fill matrix:

  // row 1:
  // 6.2500 -18.6950i, -5.0000 +15.0000i, -1.2500 + 3.7500i, 0, 0 ;
  YBus.Value[1,1] := cmplx(  6.2500, -18.6950 );
  YBus.Value[1,2] := cmplx( -5.0000,  15.0000 );
  YBus.Value[1,3] := cmplx( -1.2500, 3.7500 );
  YBus.Value[1,4] := cmplx( 0, 0 );
  YBus.Value[1,5] := cmplx( 0, 0 );

  // row 2:
  // -5.0000 +15.0000i, 10.8333 -32.4150i, -1.6667 + 5.0000i, -1.6667 + 5.0000i, -2.5000 + 7.5000i;
  YBus.Value[2,1] := cmplx( -5.0000, 15.0000 );
  YBus.Value[2,2] := cmplx( 10.8333,  -32.4150 );
  YBus.Value[2,3] := cmplx( -1.6667, 5.0000 );
  YBus.Value[2,4] := cmplx( -1.6667, 5.0000 );
  YBus.Value[2,5] := cmplx( -2.5000, 7.5000 );

  // row 3:
  // -1.2500 + 3.7500i, -1.6667 + 5.0000i, 12.9167 -38.6950i, -10.0000 +30.0000i, 0;
  YBus.Value[3,1] := cmplx( -1.2500, 3.7500 );
  YBus.Value[3,2] := cmplx( -1.6667,   5.0000 );
  YBus.Value[3,3] := cmplx( 12.9167, -38.6950 );
  YBus.Value[3,4] := cmplx( -10.0000, 30.0000 );
  YBus.Value[3,5] := cmplx( 0, 0 );

  // row 4:
  // 0, -1.6667 + 5.0000i, -10.0000 +30.0000i, 12.9167 -38.6950i, -1.2500 + 3.7500i;
  YBus.Value[4,1] := cmplx( 0, 0 );
  YBus.Value[4,2] := cmplx( -1.6667,   5.0000 );
  YBus.Value[4,3] := cmplx( -10.0000, 30.0000 );
  YBus.Value[4,4] := cmplx( 12.9167, -38.6950 );
  YBus.Value[4,5] := cmplx( -1.2500, 3.7500 );

  // row 5:
  // 0, -2.5000 + 7.5000i, 0, -1.2500 + 3.7500i, 3.7500 -11.2100i
  YBus.Value[5,1] := cmplx( 0, 0 );
  YBus.Value[5,2] := cmplx( -2.5000,   7.5000 );
  YBus.Value[5,3] := cmplx( 0, 0 );
  YBus.Value[5,4] := cmplx( -1.2500, 3.7500 );
  YBus.Value[5,5] := cmplx( 3.7500, -11.2100 );


  // compute inverse of complex matrix using relation:
  // http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/49373-complex-matrix-inversion-by-real-matrix-inversion
  // Given a complex square matrix M = A + i*B,
  // its inverse is also a complex square matrix Z = X + i*Y,
  // where A, B and X, Y are all real matrices. It is found that
  //         M^-1 = Z or
  // (A + i*B)^-1 = (A + B*A^-1*B)^-1 - i*(B + A*B^-1*A)^-1
  // Provided that those matrices involved inversion must be nonsingular.

  // with performance profiling:
  timeStart := now;
  for n := 1 to cInversionCount do
  begin
    // Create real part matrix:
    YBusRe := TFArr2D.Create( YBus.Lo1, YBus.Hi1, YBus.Lo2, YBus.Hi2);
    for row := 1 to YBus.Dim1 do
    begin
      for col := 1 to YBus.Dim2 do
      begin
         YBusRe[row, col] := YBus[row, col].Re;
      end;
    end;
    // Create imaginary part matrix:
    YBusIm := TFArr2D.Create( YBus.Lo1, YBus.Hi1, YBus.Lo2, YBus.Hi2);
    for row := 1 to YBus.Dim1 do
    begin
      for col := 1 to YBus.Dim2 do
      begin
         YBusIm[row, col] := YBus[row, col].Im;
      end;
    end;

    // compute inverse of real matrices:
    YBusReInv := PseudoinverseMt( YBusRe );
    YBusImInv := PseudoinverseMt( YBusIm );

    // compute:
    // (A + B*A^-1*B)^-1 - i*(B + A*B^-1*A)^-1
    ZBusRe := PseudoinverseMt( MtAddMt( YBusRe, MtxMt( MtxMt(YBusIm, YBusReInv ), YBusIm ) ) );
    ZBusIm := PseudoinverseMt( MtAddMt( YBusIm, MtxMt( MtxMt( YBusRe, YBusImInv ), YBusRe ) ) );

    // and finally combine to inverse complex matrix:
    ZBus :=  TCArr2D.Create( YBus, False );
    for row := 1 to ZBus.Dim1 do
    begin
      for col := 1 to ZBus.Dim2 do
      begin
         ZBus[row, col] := cmplx( ZBusRe[row, col], -ZBusIm[row, col] );
      end;
    end;
  end;
  timeStop := now;

  // print results:
  Memo1.Text := 'YBus = ' + #13#10 + CMat2Str( YBus ) + #13#10+
                'YBusRe = ' + #13#10 + Mat2Str( YBusRe ) + #13#10 +
                'YBusReInv = ' + #13#10 + Mat2Str( YBusReInv ) + #13#10 +
                'Verify inverse, I = YBusRe x YBusReInv =' + #13#10 + Mat2Str( MtxMt(YBusRe, YBusReInv ) ) + #13#10 +

                'YBusIm = ' + #13#10 + Mat2Str( YBusIm ) + #13#10 +
                'YBusImInv = ' + #13#10 + Mat2Str( YBusImInv ) + #13#10 +
                'Verify inverse, I = YBusIm x YBusImInv =' + #13#10 + Mat2Str( MtxMt(YBusIm, YBusImInv ) ) + #13#10 +

                'ZBus = ' + #13#10+ CMat2Str( ZBus ) + #13#10+
                'Verify ZBus, I = YBus x ZBus = ' + #13#10+  CMat2Str( CMtxCMt( YBus, ZBus ) ) + #13#10 +
                'Performance: ' + FormatFloat('0.00', MilliSecondsBetween(timeStop, timeStart ) / cInversionCount) + ' ms for 1 inversion. Or ' +
                IntToStr( Round( 1000 / (MilliSecondsBetween(timeStop, timeStart)/cInversionCount))) + ' inversions per second. (Intel i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz)';

end;

end.
```

[image: Screenshot of inverted YBus]

Comment: Please don't use JPG for screenshots.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand thanks for pointing it out, I guess you prefer png, which it is now.